# Need to add multiple application insights results in one query

Tags: azure-application-insights

is it possible to get the query to summarize from multiple Application insights? I cant get it working with Union command.

```
Example query:

union
app("applicationinsight02").requests, 
app("applicationinsight03").requests


availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
// check whether location failed within 5m bin
| summarize _failure=iff(countif(success == 0)>0, 1, 0) by name, location, bin(timestamp, 5m)
// check whether all locations failed within 5m bin
| summarize _failureAll=iff(sum(_failure)>=3, 1, 0) by name, bin(timestamp, 5m)
// count all failed 5 minute bins and total number of bins
| summarize _failuresCount=sum(_failureAll), _totalCount=count() by name
| project ["Name"] = name,            ["SLA"] = todouble(_totalCount - _failuresCount) / todouble(_totalCount) * 100
| order by ["SLA"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like so

```
union
app("application-insights-01").requests, 
app("application-insights-02").requests
| where timestamp > ago(1h)
| summarize sum(itemCount) by appName, bin(timestamp, 5m)
```

That will summarize the requests and show you the split by appname (the app insights resource name). Amend the where clause to fit your requirements

An example for availability results with your query would look like so, just replace application-insights-01/02 with your instance names

```
union
app("application-insights-01").availabilityResults, 
app("application-insights-02").availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(1h)
| summarize _failure=iff(countif(success == 0)>0, 1, 0) by name, location, bin(timestamp, 5m)
| summarize _failureAll=iff(sum(_failure)>=3, 1, 0) by name, bin(timestamp, 5m)
| summarize _failuresCount=sum(_failureAll), _totalCount=count() by name
| project ["Name"] = name, ["SLA"] = todouble(_totalCount - _failuresCount) / todouble(_totalCount) * 100
| order by ["SLA"]
```

Comment: But is it possible to use "availabilityResults" from several Application insights? When I try to use Union first and then use the query for Availability I am getting Syntax Error.
I want to use the query for AvailabilityResults but the source need to be 3 Application Insights from different resource groups.

Comment: yes absolutely, you can query across any of the data types in App Insights from multiple resources. Updated answer with example for your use case

Comment: @RobinJohansson, if it works, you should accept it as answer by following this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)